# Не работает JS код в браузерах

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Код JS не работает в Google Chrome, opera, а в Firefox работает.
К сожалению, но всё, что находил - было связано с заменой onclick на onchange, а мне это не подходит. Буду благодарен за помощь

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

    (function calc() {
      // открытие/закрытие калькулятора

      let openCredits = document.querySelectorAll('.credit');
      let viewCalc = document.querySelector('.second_step_calc');
      let resultCredit = document.querySelector('.result_calc');

      openCredits.forEach(el => {
        if (el.getAttribute(`data-cr`)) {
          el.addEventListener('click', function() {

            viewCalc.classList.add('view_calc');
            resultCredit.classList.add('view_calc');
          })
        }
        if (el.hasAttribute(`data-cl`)) {
          el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            viewCalc.classList.remove('view_calc');
            resultCredit.classList.remove('view_calc');
          })
        }
      })
    })();

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .calc {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      margin-top: 5em;
    }

    .name_credits,
    .summa,
   .time_for_credit {
      width: 89%;
      border: 2px solid black;
      border-radius: 4%;
      background: #fff;
      padding: 1em 1.5em;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      margin-top: 1.5em;
    }

    .name_calc {
      font-size: 50px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .step_name {
      margin-top: 2em;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .second_step_calc,
    .result_calc {
      display: none;
    }

    .view_calc {
      display: block;
    }

    .credit {
      height: 1em;
      font-size: 20px;
    }

    .credit:first-child {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .summa,
    .firstPay,
    .time_for_credit {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .minus {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 1.5em 1em;
      margin-top: 2em;
      z-index: 1;
      border: none;
      background: none;
    }

    .plus {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 1.3em 2em;
      margin-top: 2.2em;
      z-index: 1;
      border: none;
      background: none;
      left: 40em;
    }

    .summa[type='number'],
    .firstPay[type='number'],
    .time_for_credit[type='number'] {
      -moz-appearance: textfield;
    }

    input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
    input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
    }

    .up-calc,
    .down-calc {
      position: absolute;
    }

    .down-calc {
      margin-top: 8em;
      left: 14em;
    }

    .two-step {
      margin-bottom: 1em;
    }


<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <section class="calc">
      <div class="container container_calc">
        <div class="calc_inner">
          <h1 class="name_calc">Кредитный калькулятор</h1>
          <div class="first_step_calc">
            <h3 class="step_name">Шаг 1: Цель кредита</h3>
            <select class="name_credits">
              <option class="credit" data-cl="1">Выберите цель кредита</option>
              <option class="credit" data-cr="1">Ипотечное кредитование</option>
              <option class="credit" data-cr="2">Автомобильное кредитование</option>
              <option class="credit" data-cr="3">Потребительский кредит</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="second_step_calc">
            <div class="pay">
              <h3 class="step_name two-step">Шаг 2: Введите параметры кредита</h3>
              <h6 class="up-calc">Стоимость недвижимости</h6>
              <input type="button" value="&mdash;" class="minus">
              <input type="number" min="200000" max="25000000" value="2000000" class="summa" step="10000">
              <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
              <small class="down-calc">От 1 200 000 до 25 000 000 рублей</small>
            </div>
    </section>

<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код JS не работает в Google Chrome, opera, а в Firefox работает. 
К сожалению, но всё, что находил - было связано с заменой onclick на onchange, а мне это не подходит. Буду благодарен за помощь

Comment: Если у вас вопрос о том, что скрипт не реагирует на выбор пункта в `<select>`, то составьте [mcve], удалив всё, что не относится к этой конкретной проблеме, чтобы вся эта кредитная муть не мельтешила в глазах. Если я не угадал и проблема в чём-то другом, то опишите, в чём конкретно проблема

Comment: Да, всё верно. При нажатии на элементы из select (там три из них с data-cr - при нажатии на них, добавляется класс view-calc и показывается  далее блок. А при нажати и на элемент с data-cl - всё закрывается. Но к сожалению работает только в Firefox. Убрал всё лишнее

Answer (score 2):

```js
let containerCredits = document.querySelector('.container_calc');
let openCredits = document.querySelector('.name_credits');


openCredits.addEventListener('change', (ev) => {
  if (!ev.target.options.selectedIndex) {
    containerCredits.classList.remove('view_calc');
    return;
  }
  containerCredits.classList.add('view_calc');
});
```

```css
.calc {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 5em;
}

.name_credits,
.summa,
.firstPay,
.time_for_credit {
  width: 89%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
}

.name_calc {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.step_name {
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.second_step_calc,
.result_calc {
  display: none;
}

.view_calc .second_step_calc,
.view_calc .result_calc {
  display: block;
}

.credit {
  height: 1em;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.credit:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.summa,
.firstPay,
.time_for_credit {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.minus {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1.5em 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.plus {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1.3em 2em;
  margin-top: 2.2em;
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  left: 40em;
}

.summa[type='number'],
.firstPay[type='number'],
.time_for_credit[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.up-calc,
.down-calc {
  position: absolute;
}

.down-calc {
  margin-top: 8em;
  left: 14em;
}

.two-step {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.firstPay,
.range_time {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 4em;
}

.firstPay_up {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -2em;
}

.range_pay,
.range_time {
  width: 89%;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.right_out_range_time {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 29em;
  margin-top: -1.6em;
}

.range_pay[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.range_pay[type=range]::-moz-range-track,
.range_time[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 1px;
}

.range_pay[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb,
.range_time[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #2C36F2;
  border: 1px solid #2C36F2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container_calc {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.result_calc {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  padding: 3em 4em;
  width: 36%;
}

.name_sec_result {
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
}

.result_inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.right_side_second,
.right_side_third {
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.second_line h5,
.third_line h5 {
  margin-bottom: -0.1em;
}

.btn_accept {
  margin-top: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn_accepted {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #2C36F2;
  border: 1px #fff solid;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border-radius: 5%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
}

.btn_accepted:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="calc">
  <div class="container container_calc">
    <div class="calc_inner">
      <h1 class="name_calc">Кредитный калькулятор</h1>
      <div class="first_step_calc">
        <h3 class="step_name">Шаг 1: Цель кредита</h3>
        <select class="name_credits">
          <option class="credit">Выберите цель кредита</option>
          <option class="credit">Ипотечное кредитование</option>
          <option class="credit">Автомобильное кредитование</option>
          <option class="credit">Потребительский кредит</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="second_step_calc">
        <div class="pay">
          <h3 class="step_name two-step">Шаг 2: Введите параметры кредита</h3>
          <h6 class="up-calc">Стоимость недвижимости</h6>
          <input type="button" value="&mdash;" class="minus">
          <input type="number" min="200000" max="25000000" value="2000000" class="summa" step="10000">
          <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
          <small class="down-calc">От 1 200 000 до 25 000 000 рублей</small>
        </div>
        <div class="firstPayed">
          <h6 class="firstPay_up">Первоначальный взнос</h6>
          <input type="number" value="200000" class="firstPay">
          <input type="range" class="range_pay" min="10" max="100" value="10" step="1">
          <h6 class="out_range">10 %</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="time_credit">
          <input type="number" class="time_for_credit" value="5">
          <input type="range" class="range_time" min="5" max="30" value="5" step="1">
          <h6 class="out_range_time">5 лет</h6>
          <h6 class="right_out_range_time">30 лет</h6>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="use_check"> Использовать материнский капитал
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="result_calc">
      <h4 class="name_sec_result">Наше предложение</h4>
      <div class="result_inner">
        <div class="second_line">
          <div class="left_side_second">
            <h5 class="summa_ip">0 рублей</h5>
            <small>Сумма ипотеки</small>
          </div>
          <div class="right_side_second">
            <h5>0 рублей</h5>
            <small>Ежемесячный платёж</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="third_line">
          <div class="left_side_third">
            <h5 class="percent">0%</h5>
            <small>процентная ставка</small>
          </div>

          <div class="right_side_third">
            <h5>0 рублей</h5>
            <small>Необходимый доход</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn_accept">
        <a href="#" class="btn_accepted">Оформить заявку</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: К сожалению, но не работает в Chrome, в Firefox до этого и у меня работало всё, а вот в Ghrome нет

Comment: @Lordeckiy В каком смысле не работает?  Там нечему глючить. Скачайте другой браузер на хромиуме и проверьте, возможно у вас в браузере что-то не так.